# How to restore a default header's/message view in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

*All* and *Unread* headers are smaller and there's this strange filter panel.
The language doesn't matter; the first screenshot is from the web.
I accidentally hit some key-combination and I can't go back to the first view now.

How do I get Outlook to go back to how it looks in the first screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

### You accidentally hid the ribbon

Use one of the following methods to turn it back on:

#### Using the Mouse

1. In the upper-right corner of the Outlook window click the **Ribbon Display Options** button.
   [image]
2. On the fly-out menu, click **Show Tabs and Commands**.
   [image]

#### Using the Keyboard

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to toggle between collapsing and displaying the ribbon.
- When the ribbon is not *fully* collapsed, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to toggle between showing and hiding the content of the tabs on the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

On Outlook ribbon, open the **View** tab, click the **Change View** button and select the **Compact** mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try thims's suggestion first, if you are already in the **Compact** view, it could also be that you accidentally turned off the Outlook reading pane. Under **View** tab, **Reading Pane**, select **Right** to show the reading pane.